# Is there a way to use multiple ng-click's on a single button?

Tags: angularjs, button, angularjs-ng-click

This is my current attempt, both do not work at the same time

```
    <button ng-click="actionType=false" ng-click="mapValues()">Back</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just chain them:

```
  <button ng-click="mapValues(); actionType=false;">Back</button>
```